# Google Colab is not downloading files anymore

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-colaboratory

I'm using Google Colab to work with images. Basically, the output consists in 700 images in `.jpg` format, stored with the format `output_0.jpg`, `output_1.jpg` and so on. The images are stored correctly in Google virtual hard disc but I can't download them on my hard disc.
Code as follows:

```
for i in range(1000):
    try:
        files.download('output_{}.jpg'.format(i))
    except:
        continue
```

The cell starts running but gets stuck running with no errors (some days ago was working fine). Automatic file download and cookies are allowed in Chrome preferences.
Can someone help me please? thanks a lot.

Comment: Please share a self-contained notebook that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Reduce the range size and use multiple cells one after another to download large no of files.
like `range(0,250): ,range(250,500): etc`

Answer (score 0):

You aren't getting any errors because of the 'except:' part. The way you used except just silences all errors that occur.

You probably want to print the error that's occurring. You can do that by changing

```
except:
```

to

```
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

This way the error message will be printed.